# pass values from one excel sheet to another sheet

Tags: excel

I have two sheets sheet 1 and sheet 2, what I have to do is copy the values in sheet 1 to sheet 2

sheet 1 : I have two type of users with corresponding weights

```
user 1    user 2     7
user 1    user 3     19
user 1    user 7     5
user 3    user 2     1
user 2    user 7     1
```

sheet 2

```
            user 1 user 2 user 3  user 7
user 1        
user 3       
user 2        
user 7
```

The final result should be something like this: user 1 - > user two has weight 7 so this value appears in that cell and so on

```
             user 1 user 2 user 3  user 7
user 1        0        7     19       5
user 3        0        1      0       0
user 2        0        0      0       1
user 7        0        0      0       0
```

Is there a way to do this? I know I can pass values between two excel sheets but I'm confused how to do this in this case

UPDATED: CIRCULAR REFERENCE ERROR

[image]

sheet 2
 [image]

Comment: it have many ways do you try this link you can find your solution . https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-pull-data-from-one-Excel-sheet-to-another-automatically

Comment: count of users is dynamic or just these values?

Comment: @GowthamShiva dynamic , it's just a sample data , the original data has almost 5k values

Comment: Open both spreadsheets. In the spreadsheet where you want the information to appear click on that cell and enter the equal sign. Then go to the Windows tab and choose the other spreadsheet. Click on the cell that you want to import the information from. Then hit enter.
This should work. If you are using a new version of Office or Visio the tab may be titled differently.

Comment: @AshishShahi it works but only for small amount of data, I have almost 5k records in the sheet :/

Comment: Is there any possibility of duplication for combination of Column 1 and 2? e.g  user 3, user 2 appearing again in a later row?

Comment: You broad your Knowledge these idea. My work is Giving Only idea.

Comment: You check My First Link It is better Idea

Comment: @NiteshHalai no, there are no duplications of entire row excluding weights, user 3 -> user 2 won't appear again

Comment: @melissa You can use PivotTable to get it down to minutes https://www.timeatlas.com/excel-pivot-tables/

Comment: @Slai will it work for 10,000 x 10,000 matrix?

Comment: @melissa I didn't think about checking .. seems like PivotTable is limited to [256 Value fields](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#tblID0EAABAACBABAAA). The alternative in newer version of Excel is [PowerPivot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413465%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both the sample you have given starts from the top left of the sheet, enter the following formula in B2 (for user 1, user 1) and drag across the table:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$C:$C,Sheet1!$A:$A,$A2,Sheet1!$B:$B,B$1)
```

[image]

The output will be:

```
        user 1  user 2  user 3  user 7
user 1  0       7       19      5
user 2  0       0       0       1
user 3  0       1       0       0
user 7  0       0       0       0
```

[image]

It uses the users in the row and column as the criteria to match the same in column 1 and 2 of sheet 1, and adds the weight. This will work regardless of whether there is duplication or not.

Comment: It's not working for the user 2 column, it's giving 0 value on both user 1 -> user 2 and user3->user 2

Comment: Can you please check whether the formulas are matching, especially the $ signs. Added screenshots for user1 and user2 columns for your reference.

Comment: The formula is giving me circular reference error now :/

Comment: There may be a difference in the location of your data.. The formula works without any error from my side and the output matches with what you want. 

Please explain the layout of your data in both sheets and provide the exact formula you are using. Screenshot would be better.

Comment: Your data layout is exactly the same as mine, and formula is also the same. I don't know what may be going wrong.

Comment: Is there a specific location I should place my files? or specific file names?

Comment: The formula does not depend on location of files or file names. It only reference to the sheet name (Sheet1 in this case)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138708/discussion-between-nitesh-halai-and-melissa).